# Is there a way to capture the alert ok button click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to capture the alert ok button click event? In jQuery?

Comment: Are you talking about a `confirm()` Javascript modal prompt?

Comment: If you want to keep the alert window when users click ok, you cannot. However, alert() is executed synchronously which means any code you have after alert() will be executed after the button is clicked.

Comment: No, and there's no need to do so - the next thing that happens after the `alert()` is dismissed is that the code continues to execute. Thus, you implicitly know that it's been clicked.

Comment: As it's name says, it is an alert to the user. Nothing but an alert. Once user acknowledges next line will be executed.

Answer (score 17):

The `alert()` function is `synchronous` and you can't verify what was clicked (it does not return anything), so the code below the call will be executed after it is closed (ok or close button). The alert is not used to gain user input. It is an alert, a message to the user. If you need to check what the user want, you should use `confirm()`. Note that the function name tells its purpose like alert.

Something like:

```
// if the ok button is clicked, result will be true (boolean)
var result = confirm( "Do you want to do this?" );

if ( result ) {
    // the user clicked ok
} else {
    // the user clicked cancel or closed the confirm dialog.
}
```

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Thanks for your complement Jared!

Answer (score 15):

Alert is a **blocking** function, means, if you don't close it, the code below will not execute.
So you don't have to capture the alert close event, just write down the code below that alert, when alert window will be closed the code below will be executed automatically.

See example below:

```js
alert("Close Me");
// Write down the code here, which will executed only after the alert close
console.log("This code is executed after alert")
```

Comment: Great answer.. You nailed this one..

Answer (score 10):

**Disclaimer:** This is a very bad thing to do.

Technically you could hook into it with this code:

```
window.alert = function(al, $){
    return function(msg) {
        al(msg);
        $(window).trigger("okbuttonclicked");
    };
}(window.alert, window.jQuery);



$(window).on("okbuttonclicked", function() {
    console.log("you clicked ok");
});

alert("something");
```

​

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W4d7J/1/

Comment: *This isn't cross-browser and is a very bad thing to do.* Maybe you should put that first... LOL

Comment: I wonder if it works in IE without `.call` since it would be implicitly a method on `window`... Edit: It does work on IE7 for me lol

Comment: I put the question in my favorites for your answer.

Comment: is there a solution without jquery?

Answer (score 2):

There is no event for the window.alert(). Basically the next line after it is called when they click ok. I am not sure why you would need to listen for it.

Comment: There is an `alert()`-like native prompt, `confirm()`, which does give an `boolean` response. My guess is the OP had the wrong terminology.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JAlert](https://htmlguyllc.github.io/jAlert/) and assign a click handler to the ok button.

Something like

```
jAlert("Alert message goes here."); 
$('#popup_ok').bind('click',function(){
   //Do operation after clicking ok button.
   function_do_operation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in a site I created and it worked perfectly :

```
<a href="javascript:var rslt=confirm('Cancel Appointment Creation');if(rslt){window.open('http://www.the_website_I_want_to_navigate_to.com')}else{}"> << Back </a>
```