# Trigger event on an alert box

Tags: javascript, events, alert

My question is: is there a way to target an element in the alert box, specifically the 'ok' button or which would stimulate the 'enter' key press. I have tried doing this code on the console without any success:

```
var e = $.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 13}); 
$("alert").trigger(e);
```

Comment: Have you tried `keyup` and `keypress`?

Comment: You can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640248/is-there-a-way-to-capture-the-alert-ok-button-click-event

Comment: Nope, you can not add event handlers for native popups.

Answer (score 0):

Popups such as `alert` halt execution of JavaScript, so you can't listen for an event on them.  Better to use a modal popup such as [Bootstrap's](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).