# Javascript Alert Window Redirects to Another Webpage

Tags: javascript, php, alert

```
    <?php

session_start();

include_once "connect.php";

$fullName = $_POST['fullname'];
$userName = $_POST['username'];
$emailAdd = $_POST['email'];
$passWord = $_POST['password'];
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where USERNAME = '$username' ");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

  if($fullName == "")
  {

?>
    <script>
      alert("Full Name is required!");
      window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
    </script>
<?php
  }

    else
    {
      if ($userName == "")
      {
?>
        <script>
          alert("Invalid username!");
          window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
        </script>
 <?php     
      }

        else
        {
          if($userName == $result['USERNAME'])
          {
?>
            <script>
              alert("Username already exists!");
              window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
            </script>
<?php
          }

            else
            {
              if ($emailAdd == $result['EMAIL']) 
              {
?>
                <script>
                  alert("Email address is required!");
                  window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
                </script>
<?php
              }

                else
                {
                  if ($passWord == "")
                  {
?>
                    <script>
                      alert("Username is required!");
                      window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
                    </script>
 <?php     
                  }

                    else
                    {
                      if($_POST['password']==$_POST['confirmpass'])
                      {
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (FULLNAME, USERNAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD) 
                        VALUES ('$fullName', '$userName', '$emailAdd', '$passWord')" );
                        mysql_close();
?>    
                        <script>
                          alert("Registered Successfully!");
                          window.location.href = "index.php";
                        </script>
<?php
                      }

                        else
                        {
?>
                          <script>
                            alert("Password and Confirm Password do not match");
                            window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
                          </script>
<?php
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   

?>
```

It works fine. But the problem is: **the alert window shows to another web page and NOT within the webpage** It is okay but it looks awful to direct the user to another web page without having contents there. If you could help me please on how to fix this and make the javascript alert window display on the same web page only. Actually, I have tried some solutions like this..

```
if($fullName == "")
{
  echo '<script>';
  echo 'alert("Full Name is required!")';
  echo 'window.location.href = "registeruser.php"';
  echo '</script>';
}
```

Comment: try putting a `/` before the `registereduser.php` or put the exact path with domain name.

Comment: Add complete Path to  `echo 'window.location.href = "registeruser.php"';`

Comment: Nope. It's not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to capture the alert ok button click event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640248/is-there-a-way-to-capture-the-alert-ok-button-click-event)

Comment: Maybe you should consider doing this within an AJAX-Request. Btw., please never do something like `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where USERNAME = '$username' ")`, because you open the doors to SQL injection.

Comment: Might be because you are echoing script above your html, on each submission the page reloads and the echo executes (without loading html). To show the alert above html, move your php code below HTML code.
I must tell, this is NOT A GOOD PRACTICE but will fulfil your requirement.
Also, DO NOT USE MYSQL now (its deprecated), USE MYSQLi OR PDO.

Comment: It is simple. On submitting the registration form, send the data to same file. Write the PHP and validation code(Whatever code mentioned in the question) in the same file where you have designed registration form. Then remove `window.location.href` statement. Thats it.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to redirect the user to `registereduser.php` without erasing whatever the user has typed in any field on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Hello do you try to use ajax with jquery

now is your script just return a json object to say if all is ok
    //reg.php

```
session_start();
header('Content-type: application/json');

include_once "connect.php";

// result we return to the user
$response = ['error' => false, 'message' => ''];

$fullName = $_POST['fullname'];
$userName = $_POST['username'];
$emailAdd = $_POST['email'];
$passWord = $_POST['password'];
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where USERNAME = '$username' ");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

if($fullName == "") {
    $response['message'] = 'Full Name is required!';
    $response['error'] = true;
} else {
    if ($userName == "") {
        $response['message'] = 'Invalid username!';
        $response['error'] = true; 
    } else {
        if($userName == $result['USERNAME']) {
            $response['message'] = 'Username already exists!';
            $response['error'] = true;
        } else {
            if ($emailAdd == $result['EMAIL'])  {
                $response['message'] = 'Email address is required!';
                $response['error'] = true;
            } else {
                if ($passWord == "") {
                    $response['message'] = 'Username is required!';
                    $response['error'] = true;
                } else {
                    if($_POST['password']==$_POST['confirmpass']) {
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (FULLNAME, USERNAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD)  VALUES ('$fullName', '$userName', '$emailAdd', '$passWord')" );
                        mysql_close();
                        $response['message'] = 'OK';
                        $response['error'] = false;
                    } else {
                        $response['message'] = 'Password and Confirm Password do not match';
                        $response['error'] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

die(json_encode($response));
```

and
    // registration.php

```
<form method=POST action="reg.php" id="myForm">
<!--input goes here-->
</form>

<script src="//path to jquery"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(() => {

    $('#myForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post('reg.php', $(this).serialize())
            .done((datas) => {


                if(datas.erreur) {
                    alert(datas.message);
                } else {
                    alert('registration succesfully');
                }
            }).fail(() => {
                alert('connect error !!!');
            });
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use base url and then paste your Custom path to your page like:

```
<?php
if($fullName == "")
{
?>
  <script>
   var MyBaseURL = <?php echo BASE_URL_CONSTANT?>
   var customURL = MyBaseURL."/registeruser.php";
   alert("Full Name is required!");
   window.location.href = customURL;
  </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

And you should avoid Echoing script, use regular script block with Enclosing php tags.

Comment: I think he's talking about the page that displayed while the alert is happening, not the page it redirects to after the alert.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the alert on the `registeruser.php` page. Have the PHP script do:

```
header("Location: registeruser.php?message=" . urlencode("Invalid username"));
```

Then `registeruser.php` can do:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['message'])) {
    ?>
    <script>
    alert(<?php echo json_encode($_GET['message']); ?>);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Did you missed something ?  `isset($_GET['message'`

Comment: @TarangP I have that, what's the question?

Comment: i think the right syntax is isset($_GET['message'])

Comment: Ahh, why didn't you just say I made a typo and left out the `]`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try rendering some html after the session_start().
e.g.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login Message</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

That should provide a page for the message to appear on.
Although, even better, in my opinion: Don't break out of php at all and use the php header() function to take you to the appropriate page where required.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it like this:

```
if($fullName == "")
{
    echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Full Name is required!')</script>";
    echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location.replace('page.php?id=".$crmId."'); </script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need, as others said, to move your logic to the end of HTML. Second, you would need to implement this logic at the page you are looking to load, not the one that redirects. It's a 2 step logic. E.g.:

You would need to implement window.location at your current script.

Then, right before  tag of the page you want the user to be redirected:

```
<?php
if($fullName == "")
{
  echo '<script>';
  echo 'alert("Full Name is required!")';
  echo '</script>';
}
?>
</body>
```

So, doing it, after the page loaded, it will alert correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your location href syntax is wrong. It should be like this :

```
if($fullName == "")
{
  echo '<script>';
  echo 'alert("Full Name is required!")';
  echo 'window.location.href = SITE_URL."registeruser.php"';
  echo '</script>';
}
```

Here SITE_URL is your projects root path like   http://localhost/yourproject/

Answer (score 0):

this script will execute on the same page but you have to use form like this

```
<form method=POST action="">
<!--input goes here-->
</form>



<?php

session_start();

include_once "connect.php";
if(isset($_POST[submit])){
$fullName = $_POST['fullname'];
$userName = $_POST['username'];
$emailAdd = $_POST['email'];
$passWord = $_POST['password'];
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where USERNAME = '$username' ");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

  if($fullName == "")
  {


  echo '    <script>
      alert("Full Name is required!");
      window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
    </script>';

  }

    else
    {
      if ($userName == "")
      {

        echo '   <script>
          alert("Invalid username!");
          window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
        </script>';

      }

        else
        {
          if($userName == $result['USERNAME'])
          {

          echo '  <script>
              alert("Username already exists!");
              window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
            </script>';

          }

            else
            {
              if ($emailAdd == $result['EMAIL']) 
              {

                echo '<script>
                  alert("Email address is required!");
                  window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
                </script>';

              }

                else
                {
                  if ($passWord == "")
                  {

                   echo ' <script>
                      alert("Username is required!");
                      window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
                    </script>';

                  }

                    else
                    {
                      if($_POST['password']==$_POST['confirmpass'])
                      {
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (FULLNAME, USERNAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD) 
                        VALUES ('$fullName', '$userName', '$emailAdd', '$passWord')" );
                        mysql_close();

                      echo '   <script>
                          alert("Registered Successfully!");
                          window.location.href = "index.php";
                        </script>';

                      }

                        else
                        {

                         echo '  <script>
                            alert("Password and Confirm Password do not match");
                            window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
                          </script>';

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

or else you can use like this
*registration.php*

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET[fname]) && $_GET[fname]==1)
    echo ' <script>
          alert("Full Name is required!");
        </script>';
  if(isset($_GET[uname]) && $_GET[uname]==1 )
      echo '   <script>
          alert("Invalid username!");
        </script>';
  if(isset($_GET[uname]) && $_GET[uname]==2 )
    echo '  <script>
              alert("Username already exists!");
            </script>';
  if(isset($_GET[pwrd]) && $_GET[pwrd]==2 )
  echo '  <script>alert("Password and Confirm Password do not match");
                          </script>';
  if(isset($_GET[pwrd]) && $_GET[pwrd]==1 )
     echo '  <script>alert("Password is invalid");
                          </script>';
    if(isset($_GET[mail]) && $_GET[mail]==1 )
      echo '  <script>alert("invalid mailid");
                          </script>';

?>
<form method=POST action="reg.php">
<!--input goes here-->
</form>
```

*reg.php*

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once "connect.php";
if(isset($_POST[submit])){
$fullName = $_POST['fullname'];
$userName = $_POST['username'];
$emailAdd = $_POST['email'];
$passWord = $_POST['password'];
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where USERNAME = '$username' ");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

  if($fullName == "")
  {
              header('Location:registration.php?fname=1');


  }

    else
    {
      if ($userName == "")
      {
                header('Location:registration.php?uname=1');

      }

        else
        {
          if($userName == $result['USERNAME'])
          {

           header('Location:registration.php?uname=2');
          }

            else
            {
              if ($emailAdd == $result['EMAIL']) 
              {
               header('Location:registration.php?mail=1');

              }

                else
                {
                  if ($passWord == "")
                  {

                                header('Location:registration.php?pwrd=1');
                  }

                    else
                    {
                      if($_POST['password']==$_POST['confirmpass'])
                      {
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (FULLNAME, USERNAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD) 
                        VALUES ('$fullName', '$userName', '$emailAdd', '$passWord')" );
                        mysql_close();

                      echo '   <script>
                          alert("Registered Successfully!");
                          window.location.href = "index.php";
                        </script>';

                      }

                        else
                        {

           header('Location:registration.php?pwrd=2');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code

```
    <?php

session_start();

include_once "connect.php";

$fullName = $_POST['fullname'];
$userName = $_POST['username'];
$emailAdd = $_POST['email'];
$passWord = $_POST['password'];
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where USERNAME = '$username' ");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

  if($fullName == "")
  {

?>
    <script>
      if(alert("Full Name is required!"))
      {
            window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
        }
    </script>
<?php
  }

    else
    {
      if ($userName == "")
      {
?>
        <script>
          if(alert("Invalid username!"))
          {
            window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
            }
        </script>
 <?php     
      }

        else
        {
          if($userName == $result['USERNAME'])
          {
?>
            <script>
              if(alert("Username already exists!"))
              {
                    window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
                }
            </script>
<?php
          }

            else
            {
              if ($emailAdd == $result['EMAIL']) 
              {
?>
                <script>
                  if(alert("Email address is required!"))
                  {
                        window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
                    }
                </script>
<?php
              }

                else
                {
                  if ($passWord == "")
                  {
?>
                    <script>
                      if(alert("Username is required!"))
                      {
                            window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
                        }
                    </script>
 <?php     
                  }

                    else
                    {
                      if($_POST['password']==$_POST['confirmpass'])
                      {
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (FULLNAME, USERNAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD) 
                        VALUES ('$fullName', '$userName', '$emailAdd', '$passWord')" );
                        mysql_close();
?>    
                        <script>
                          if(alert("Registered Successfully!"))
                          {
                                window.location.href = "index.php";
                            }
                        </script>
<?php
                      }

                        else
                        {
?>
                          <script>
                           if(alert("Password and Confirm Password do not match"))
                            {
                                  window.location.href = "registeruser.php";
                            }
                          </script>
<?php
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   

?>
```

this code redirect page when user click ok button.
alert massage show before the page redirect

Comment: Please add more description regarding your answer.