# How to trigger start a countdown timer after pop alert?

Tags: countdowntimer

How to trigger or start a countdown timer after pop alert?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">    
  alert("Timer Will Start!");
  counter.start();    
</script>
```

Comment: Please consider adding more details to you questions, including your attempts to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the javascript alert is synchronous and also doesn't have a return value so you could use the confirm dialog instead if you really need a return value from the dialog. Refer to this question [Is there a way to capture the alert ok button click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640248/is-there-a-way-to-capture-the-alert-ok-button-click-event)

Also, since the alert is synchronous you can just put the alert dialog before you start the counter and it won't start until you close the dialog.

```
function startCounter() {
  alert('Timer starts!');
  counter.start();
}
```

[JSFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ph3ftc6b)