# Anchor tag in inline javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing a static html/css website. In the contact page of the website, I have written an onclick function using inline js.

```js
function goback() {
  alert("Thank you for contacting us ");
}
```

```html
<button class="app-form-button" onclick="goback()">SEND</button>
```

I want to revert back to the home page once the person clicks on the popup on click function. But I don't have any idea on how to add an anchor tag to create a reference url to the home page within the script tag. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: did you mean to append as a child in your div element? or redirect to another page?

Comment: @callmenikk No I'm not using node interface here. I wanted to go back to the home page once I click ok on the onclick popup .

Comment: @SreelakshmiG I have added [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68966540/13833218) below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46974454/13833218)

> Alert is a blocking function, means, if you don't close it, the code
> below will not execute. So you don't have to capture the alert close
> event, just write down the code below that alert, when alert window
> will be closed the code below will be executed automatically.

So, you can redirect the user to homepage after the `alert` statement via [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href)

```html
<button class="app-form-button" onclick="goback()">SEND</button>
<script>
  function goback() {
    alert("Thank you for contacting us ");
    window.location.href = "your homepage url";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I wanted

Comment: @SreelakshmiG Welcome. Consider [upvoting and accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you found it useful

Answer (score 1):

You can use window object's propery location

after the alert, add this:

```
window.location.href="/index.html" /// or any other name of your homepage
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Location Replace It Won't Work here for some disabilities of stackoverflow

```html
<button class="app-form-button" onclick="goback()">SEND</button>

<script>  
   function goback(){  
        alert("Thank you for contacting us "); 
        location.replace("https://www.google.com/")
        }
</script>
```